# I have a issues with flutter_screen_wake library error in Ios

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a problem with flutter_screen_wake library, because when i work in ios platform, it bring me the next error:
type String is not a subtype of type double in type cast

[image]
I use
Flutter v.2.2.2
Dart v. 2.13.3
flutter_screen_wake v.1.0.0